# Writing a loop that brings in two different date formats

Tags: sql, r

I need to use R for writing a query coming from a database my R environment is connected to. The structure of the query looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE cph.table_id ADD PARTITION (event_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD')
LOCATION 's3://external-dwh-company-com/id-to-idl/YYYYMMDD'
```

So for example, today's addition would like as such:

```
ALTER TABLE cph.table_id ADD PARTITION (event_date = '2018-08-02')
LOCATION 's3://external-dwh-company-com/id-to-idl/20180802'
```

The issue is, I need to be doing this for every data going back to 03/01/2018.

So the steps would look like:

```
initial_query <- paste(#however the above query would be formatted with the dates)

results_query <- dbGetQuery(conn,  initial_query)
```

But yeah, the biggest hurdle for me is 1.) Figuring out the `paste` formatting for that first part and 2.) Creating a loop that will allow me to run the above steps until the current date.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add partitions for each day? Are records at hourly/minute levels? Or millions of rows per *event_date*? What RDBMS is this?

Comment: @Parfait Yes. What do you mean by RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Consider looping through the range of days since a targeted begin date with `lapply` and `seq`, concatenating strings with `sprintf` and corresponding date format:

```
# GET DIFFERENCE BETWEEN TODAY AND DESIRED BEGIN DATE
date_diff <- Sys.Date() - as.Date("2018-03-01")

date_diff[[1]]
# 155

sql <- "ALTER TABLE cph.table_id ADD PARTITION (event_date = '%s')
        LOCATION 's3://external-dwh-company-com/id-to-idl/%s'"

# RUN QUERY SEQUENTIALLY ADDING TO BEGIN DATE
output <- lapply(seq(1, date_diff[[1]]), function(i)
             dbGetQuery(conn, sprintf(sql, strftime(as.Date("2018-03-01") + i, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                           strftime(as.Date("2018-03-01") + i, "%Y%m%d"))))
```